# two columns of text, how to make it fill the page to the bottom for all resolutions?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this layout for notebook and desktops:
[image]

when the screen has more height, the text should still fill to the bottom of the page. It would be possible to upsize the font. The problem is, sizing up the font or using things like `vh` as the font increases in size it will use more lines as well, and thus, creating extra lines, that will finally lead to more unexpected height. To avoid that we could define, probably, the width of the columns to be defined in `vh` as well. This will cause problems though if the screen is actually not wide enough to make it fit.

Am I over complicating things, is there a simpler solution?

Comment: provide code in order to help you

Comment: Instead of complicating things, just try to 1. provide markup and 2. define exactly what is the desired output, using simple words

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the `font-size`, you could change the `line-height` property based on the viewport height. So when the screen is larger, the space between lines increases, without creating the "extra" height you may get when increasing the font size. This may not always look aesthetically pleasing though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged it as `css3`, I would recommend that you take a look at css `column-count` attribute:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

This way you can just set the height (as a %, for instance) and let css take care of it for you.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: this will overflow though

Comment: Only if you want it to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you may  want some alternatives behavior such as restrain width on big screen, center vertically page instead stretching, resize font-size but keep one safe valu to make it still readable ...

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
body {
  margin: auto;
}
main {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
header,
footer {
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: calc(0.75vh + 0.75vw)
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px),
(max-height: 400px) {
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</main>
<footer>footer
  <footer>
```

[Demo to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KVBBwR)